# Powers of Stephen Hawking

Tags: futurama

In the "Crimes of the Hot", most, if not all, of Earth's scientists gathered to a single location to try and solve the global warming crisis.  During the convention, Dr. Hubert Farnsworth and Dr. Wernstrom had an argument which was then stopped by Stephen Hawking's Eye lasers.  Stephen Hawking later then said "I did not know I can do that".

Does that mean he had other powers?  Also, how did he obtain those powers?  Was it because his intellect was so high?  Or was it simillar to something applied like the *Miracle Cream*?

Comment: This line *could* be a 3PO reference. But I wouldn't know what it might possibly mean.

Answer (score 4):

The comment he makes indicates nothing more than the fact that Hawking did not in fact know that he could shoot lasers from his eyes, and is likely not a reference to anything specific. (The C-3PO reference is possible, but unlikely.)

The question of what further powers he has, or how he gained them, is never addressed in the show, but he is the only human depicted as having super powers on that order, which speaks to the powers being mental in origin.